# python distribute elements of a list into part of a sql query

Tags: python, mysql, iterable-unpacking

In python, I have the following sql query:

```
qry = "insert into golden_table (alpha, beta, week1, week2, week3, clust_list, nGram) values (%s %s %s %s %s %s %s)"
```

Now I wish to do something like:

```
L = ['a', 'b', 'c']
qry % (1, 2, UNPACK(L), "herp", "derp")
```

The result would be:

```
"insert into golden_table (alpha, beta, week1, week2, week3, clust_list, nGram) values (1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c', "herp", "derp")"
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build tuples, you can use `tuple(L)` to turn a list into a tuple, and combine tuples with `+`.

Ex:

```
>>> L
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> (1,) + (2,) + tuple(L) + ("herp", "derp")
(1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'herp', 'derp')
```